# Android - MIC external for speechRecognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, microphone

I need to know which event is triggered when connecting a microphone or a headset to your device, and I am using speech recognition and have observed that does not follow the same flow as when nothing is connected to the device.

I would like to know if there is some kind of solution because the application I'm creating at the moment is tested in a Smartphone, but in the future will require connecting a microphone or a headset.

A greeting and I hope your answers

PS: At the moment in the code I have nothing on external microphone or headset, but at the moment everything is running according to device microphone and speaker.

**EDIT**

I see the way of knowing whether the headset is connected is as follows:

```
private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        switch (state) {
        case 0:
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
        }
    }
}
}
```

But how to redirect the audio input to the microphone of the headset? and the audio output to the headphone output?

Comment: You do not need anything special, the sound is rerouted automatically

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I think it depends on the device, since my Smartphone not automatically redirects the sound input or out, while there are other devices that if redirect audio output. I would like to insert in the code for those devices that do not redirect the input or output audio to headphones.

Comment: It should not depend on the device you can test in any music player, most likely your headset just does not fit the plug properly.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev ok in music player, but I want  to implement in my application, beacause in my Application don't work well